# "Hop" or "jump". Which one to use?

Tags: word-usage

Assuming that the text below is grammatically correct and even if it makes some sense in English (I simply translated it from a Portuguese text), which of the two verbs, "hop" or "jump", would best apply to the meaning of the sentence in which they are used?

"There was a time when we didn't have any worries. We had little money but life was a lot more fun. Sometimes we would spend the whole day walking around, and even though we had no idea where we were going, there was nothing stopping us from **hopping** / **jumping** onto some train or bus and spending hours admiring the beauty of the city."

Comment: The [Triple jump](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triple_jump), also known as the "hop, step, and jump", is an Olympic event that officially distinguishes between the three actions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this context both words can be used interchangeably in everyday English. As a native BrE speaker I would say either.
In other contexts they have different meanings. To hop is to jump using one leg whilst jumping uses both legs. But since it is unlikely that you would do either when boarding a train or a bus, it is always understood that you mean is that you are getting into the vehicle to go somewhere.

Comment: Thanks a lot, Peter. Please, allow me to ask a question a little out of context. What's the meaning of the abbreviation "BrE" in "a native BrE speaker"?

Comment: "British English" as opposed to AmE "American English"!

Answer (score 1):

They're both fine.

"Jumping on" feels more energetic though. So if you're old enough to get on a bus and admire a city for hours, then you're an adult, and "hopping on" is much more likely.